# java 8 stream groupingBy into collection of custom object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have the following class structure

```
public class Store {
    private Long storeId;

    private Long masterStoreId;

    private String operatorIdentifier;
}

public class StoreInfo {

    private String operatorIdentifier;

    private Set<Long> slaveStoreIds;

    public StoreInfo(String operatorIdentifier, Set<Long> slaveStoreIds) {
        super();
        this.operatorIdentifier = operatorIdentifier;
        this.slaveStoreIds = slaveStoreIds;
    }

}
```

I want to collect the "List<Store" into a "Map<Long, StoreInfo>". Is it possible to do so in a single operation/iteration?

```
List<Store> stores;

Map<Long, Set<Long>> slaveStoresAgainstMasterStore = stores.stream().collect(Collectors
                .groupingBy(Store::getMasterStoreId, Collectors.mapping(Store::getStoreId, Collectors.toSet())));

Map<Long, StoreInfo> storeInfoAgainstMasterStore = stores.stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors
                                .toMap(Store::getMasterStoreId,
                                        val -> new StoreInfo(val.getOperatorIdentifier(),
                                                slaveStoresAgainstMasterStore.get(val.getMasterStoreId())),
                                        (a1, a2) -> a1));
```

Comment: Do you really want `Map<Long, StoreInfo>` or just `List<StoreInfo>` would work for you? .. and you need to figure out what does  `(a1, a2) -> a1` do and replace it with what you intend to perform.

Comment: @Naman I don't want a ```List<StoreInfo>```. I want to collect a list of storeId against the masterStoreId in a custom StoreInfo object.

Comment: Those having same masterStoreId have same operatorIdentifier ?

Comment: @Rono yeah, masterStoreId and operatorIdentifier are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the implementation, you were attempting. You need to ensure merging capability within `StoreInfo` such as :

```
public StoreInfo(String operatorIdentifier, Long slaveStoreId) {
    this.operatorIdentifier = operatorIdentifier;
    this.slaveStoreIds = new HashSet<>();
    this.slaveStoreIds.add(slaveStoreId);
}

public static StoreInfo mergeStoreInfo(StoreInfo storeInfo1, StoreInfo storeInfo2) {
    Set<Long> slaveIds = storeInfo1.getSlaveStoreIds();
    slaveIds.addAll(storeInfo2.getSlaveStoreIds());
    return new StoreInfo(storeInfo1.getOperatorIdentifier(), slaveIds);
}
```

this would simplify the implementation of collector and you an invoke these correspondingly:

```
Map<Long, StoreInfo> storeInfoAgainstMasterStore = stores.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Store::getMasterStoreId,
                store -> new StoreInfo(store.getOperatorIdentifier(), store.getStoreId()),
                StoreInfo::mergeStoreInfo));
```

Answer (score 2):

As `masterStoreId` and `operatorIdentifier` are same same in group(comfirmed in comment) you can groupingBy both creating pair of them using `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`. Then using `Collectors.toMap` create map.

```
Map<Long, StoreInfo> storeInfoMap = 
    stores.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                      e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getMasterStoreId(),
                                                        e.getOperatorIdentifier()),
                      Collectors.mapping(Store::getStoreId, Collectors.toSet())))
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getKey(),
                            e -> new StoreInfo(e.getKey().getValue(), e.getValue())));
```